# How to kill a cmd process which was started from my java application?

Tags: java, process, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am starting a zookeeper and a Kafka server from java application.

If I try to kill these processes using the `destroyForcibly()` method, nothing happens. - I have tried using both the `destroy()` and `destroyForcibly()` methods but none seem to work.

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties"});


Thread.sleep(3000);

Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/server.properties"});


Thread.sleep(5000);

p1.destroyForcibly();
p2.destroyForcibly();
```

Is it possible to shut down cmd processes programmatically?

Comment: you spawn a cmd which spawn processes? why don't you call the end processes directly?

Comment: Because calling them directly, the servers don't seem to start

Comment: Are you trying to start those embedded within one app, or just automate starting them as external processes?

Comment: Basically I don't want to use the available implementations of embedded kafka servers. I need a local kafka server to run unit tests against. So I am trying to start them up as external processes which I would terminate once the test in finished.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Process p1 = new ProcessBuilder("C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat",
"C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties")
            .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD)
            .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD)
            .start();
```

Comment: Actually doing it this way, the zookeeper and kafka servers never start. I feel the batch files are not getting executed

Comment: They do. If you consume the stdout and stderr streams.

Comment: Just realized they are getting started but the processes are still not getting killed